# No idea How to cast Java - HTML

Tags: java, html, eclipse, casting

This program works with MySQL, Java and HTML.

In the console I can print every data of the DB, I can't in HTML

The program crashes at:

```
.replace("[BATTERYLIFE]", ((Laptop)p).getOrebatteria()+"")
```

telling me

> entities.Pc cannot be cast to entities.Laptop

I've got Smartphone-->Laptop-->Pc-->Product (--> Extends).

I have no idea how to cast them, thanking you in advance.

```
ris = ris.replace("[ID]", p.getId()) 
.replace("[CODE]", p.getCode())
.replace("[MODEL]", p.getModel())
.replace("[CPU]", ((Pc) p).getCPU())
.replace("[RAM]", ((Pc) p).getRam()+"")  
.replace("[MMA]", ((Pc) p).getMma()+"")  
.replace("[RAMTYPE]", ((Pc) p).getRamType())  
.replace("[MMATYPE]", ((Pc) p).getMmaType())  
.replace("[BATTERYLIFE]", ((Laptop)p).getOrebatteria()+"")  
.replace("[INCHES]", ((Laptop) p).getPollici()+"")  
.replace("[NETWORK]", ((Smartphone) p).getNetwork())  
.replace("[MEGAPIXEL]", ((Smartphone) p).getMegapixel()+"")  
.replace("[JACK]", ((Smartphone) p).getJack());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to cast object `p` which is of type `Pc` to `Laptop` on that line, because `p` can be `Smartphone`, `Laptop` or `Pc` you need to check if it's the correct type before casting. Casting `Laptop` to `Pc` would be fine because `Laptop extends Pc`, but not the other way around.

Try something like:

```
ris = ris.replace("[ID]", p.getId())
        .replace("[CODE]", p.getCode())
        .replace("[MODEL]", p.getModel());

if (p instanceof Pc) {
    ris = ris.replace("[CPU]", ((Pc) p).getCPU())
            .replace("[RAM]", ((Pc) p).getRam() + "")
            .replace("[MMA]", ((Pc) p).getMma() + "")
            .replace("[RAMTYPE]", ((Pc) p).getRamType())
            .replace("[MMATYPE]", ((Pc) p).getMmaType());
} else if (p instanceof Laptop) {
    ris = ris.replace("[BATTERYLIFE]", ((Laptop) p).getOrebatteria() + "")
            .replace("[INCHES]", ((Laptop) p).getPollici() + "");
} else if (p instanceof Smartphone) {
    ris = ris.replace("[NETWORK]", ((Smartphone) p).getNetwork())
            .replace("[MEGAPIXEL]", ((Smartphone) p).getMegapixel() + "")
            .replace("[JACK]", ((Smartphone) p).getJack());
}
```

Comment: Without the "else" worked, You were very helpful, thanks!